# kern.log and syslog grow too quickly

Tags: 12.04, logging, syslog

My `/var/log/kern.log` and `syslog` grow too much. What could it be?

It would be nice if I could get them to rotate after reaching 256 MB or so. Can logrotate do that? How can I set it up to rotate files by size?

I use Ubuntu 12.04 desktop 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the log files (`tail -f /var/log/kern.log`) to see what's filling them up so quickly. Something may be throwing errors and that causes them to grow. If you do, please update your question with your findings, maybe someone else can help determine what the problem is.

Also, there's no need to rotate them manually, they get rotated on a periodic basis (every day, with the 7 prior days kept in a compressed format, anything older gets deleted, except for `/var/log/messages` which rotates weekly with 4 prior weeks kept), look at `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` for the configuration.

I agree that if your log files are growing boundlessly the best thing to do is find what's causing it, because it's not normal. As a parameter my `kern.log` is under 20 MB and it has information for the past 3 days (hasn't been rotated because the rotation task hasn't run).

Comment: Bien, si gracias. Hice esto :tail -f /var/log/kern.log

Comment: c:~$ tail -f /var/log/kern.log
May  2 21:22:33 pc kernel: [ 2915.260921] [drm:intel_prepare_page_flip] *ERROR* Prepared flip multiple times
Etc,etc,etc...
Lanza eso, y sabes que con cada clic de mouse la lista se disparaba, con mas de eso. Muy amable. Gracias.

Comment: Amigos lo solucioné !, instalando busybox-syslogd , que desinstala klogd y syslogd, que previamente había instalado. En vez de  rsyslog rsyslog-gnutls rsyslog-gssapi rsyslog-mysql rsyslog-relp para probar, Así está mi ( kernlog y sys.log ) 4bit, durante mucho rato. busybox-syslogd. De nuevo, grcias. Saludos